# SQL Server 2008 : select newest rows whose sum matches a value in the row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I asked a [similar question recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955002/sql-server-select-newest-rows-whos-sum-matches-a-value), but the actual implementation proved more difficult as it had to rely on a date field, not an ID field, so I'm going to start a new question as the method will no doubt prove somewhat different.

Looking at the table below, **only** those rows whose SUM(PurchQty) are necessary to arrive at a value greater than / equal to "CurrentStock" should be returned, and those must be newest rows first, based on date.  This needs to be evaluated and row(s) returned per "ProductCode".

Therefore, given this table:

```
ID    ProductCode    Date        PurchQty    CurrentStock
1001  AB101          14/12/2016      9            14
1111  AB101          01/01/2017     18            14
1223  AB101          15/01/2017     20            14
1233  BB400          02/01/2017     50            40 
1321  AB101          31/01/2017      8            14
1400  BB400          12/12/2016     90            40
1456  CC200          13/03/2017    100            20
```

Our query should yield the result:

```
ProductCode    Date         PurchQty    CurrentStock
AB101          31/01/2017      8             14 
AB101          15/01/2017     20             14
BB400          02/01/2017     50             40
CC200          13/03/2017    100             20
```

(note these are UK dates - dd/mm/yyyy - but that is unimportant)

Comment: Why  row with `ID=1400` isn't in your output? because `sum(PurchQty)` is greater than / equal   to "CurrentStock".  Or I missed something ?

Comment: can you please add details in your output regarding first two rows for AB101. 1) mention data of column purchqty is already sum or not. if not how sum will be calculated. 2) Why there are 2 rows for same product rather it should be one if purchqty is greater than current stock for maximum date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This, This will give the desired result,
I have used recursive CTE

```
CREATE TABLE #tst (id int,ProductCode varchar(50),[Date] Datetime,PurchQty int,CurrentStock int)
INSERT INTO #tst
SELECT 1001,'AB101','2016/12/14',9,14 UNION
SELECT 1111,'AB101','2017/01/01',18,14 UNION
SELECT 1223,'AB101','2017/01/15',20,14 UNION
SELECT 1233,'BB400','2017/01/02',50,40 UNION
SELECT 1321,'AB101','2017/01/31',8,14 UNION
SELECT 1400,'BB400','2016/12/12',90,40 UNION
SELECT 1456,'CC200','2017/03/13',100,20 

;with CTE AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ProductCode order by [date] desc) as RowId,* from #tst
),CTE2 AS
(
SELECT RowId,id ,ProductCode ,[Date] ,PurchQty ,CurrentStock,PurchQty as Cum_Quantity from CTE as a WHERE RowId=1
UNION ALL
SELECT a.RowId,a.id ,a.ProductCode ,a.[Date] ,a.PurchQty ,a.CurrentStock, a.PurchQty+b.Cum_Quantity
FROM CTE a 
JOIN CTE2 as b  ON a.ProductCode=b.ProductCode 
WHERE a.RowId=b.RowId+1  AND a.[Date]<b.[Date] AND b.Cum_Quantity<b.CurrentStock
)
SELECT * from CTE2 order by ProductCode
```

Comment: This was almost perfect - I had to amend a.[Date]<b.[Date] to <= as my real world data had multiple purchase orders on single dates. Apart from a secondary issue caused by the huge amount of recursion (maxing out) of the full dataset, things are looking good!

Comment: This is way over-complicated for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You need a cumulative sum.  In SQL Server 2008, this can be done using `apply` or a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*, t2.cume_PurchQty
from t cross apply
     (select sum(PurchQty) as cume_PurchQty
      from t t2
      where t2.ProductCode = t.ProductCode and t2.Date <= t.Date
     ) t2
where t2.cume_PurchQty < t.CurrentStock;
```

In SQL Server 2012+, this is much more efficiently written using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(PurchQty) over (partition by ProductCode order by date) as cume_PurchQty
      from t
     ) t
where cume_PurchQty < CurrentStock
```

Comment: I think you have missed the requirement to segment by product code? Or I have missed something.

Comment: @Tony . . . I think you have missed something.  That is what the correlation clause does.  That is what `partition by` does.

Comment: When I run the SQL Server 2008 query, it only returns the first row of the data...

`1001  AB101          14/12/2016      9            14`

Answer (score 0):

```
;With Cte_1(ID,ProductCode,[Date],PurchQty,CurrentStock)
As
(
SELECT 1001,'AB101','14/12/2016',  9,14 Union All
SELECT 1111,'AB101','01/01/2017', 18,14 Union All
SELECT 1223,'AB101','15/01/2017', 20,14 Union All
SELECT 1233,'BB400','02/01/2017', 50,40 Union All
SELECT 1321,'AB101','31/01/2017',  8,14 Union All
SELECT 1400,'BB400','12/12/2016', 90,40 Union All
SELECT 1456,'CC200','13/03/2017',100,20
),
cte2 AS (
        SELECT ProductCode
            ,[Date]
            ,CASE 
                WHEN Sum(PurchQty) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY ProductCode
                        ,[DATE] ORDER BY ProductCode
                        ) >= CurrentStock
                    THEN PurchQty
                END SumPurchQty
            ,CurrentStock
        FROM Cte_1
        )
    ,Cte3 AS (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY ProductCode ORDER BY SumPurchQty DESC
                ) AS SeqOrder
            ,ProductCode,[DATE],SumPurchQty,CurrentStock
        FROM cte2
        )

SELECT ProductCode
    ,[Date]
    ,SumPurchQty
    ,CurrentStock
FROM Cte3
WHERE SeqOrder = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved easily by using Rank function (row_number()). I have used your sample input to populate the temp table of similar structure.

```
create table #tmp
(
ID int, productcode varchar(20), dates date, purchqty int, currstock int
)
insert into #tmp values (1001,'AB101','14-Dec-2016',9,14)
insert into #tmp values (1111,'AB101','01-Jan-2017',18,14)
insert into #tmp values (1223,'AB101','15-Jan-2017',20,14)
insert into #tmp values (1233,'BB400','02-Jan-2017',50,40)
insert into #tmp values (1321,'AB101','31-Jan-2017',8,14)
insert into #tmp values (1400,'BB400','12-Dec-2016',90,40)
insert into #tmp values (1456,'CC200','13-Mar-2017',100,20)


;with CTE AS
(
select *,row_number() over (partition by Diff,productcode order by dates desc) RID 
from (
        select *, case when purchqty-currstock<=0 then 0 else 1 end Diff
        from #tmp  
    )D 
) 
select ID,productCode,dates,purchqty,currstock 
from CTE C1
where (RID=1 and diff=1) OR (Diff=0 and dates >= (select dates from CTE C2 where C2.productcode=C1.productcode and c2.Diff=1 and RID=1))

drop table #tmp
```

Comment: This looked correct on the face of it, but I believe you have missed the need for a cumulative total for purchpty. When the dataset includes no rows with a PurchQty greater than CurrStock, no rows are returned.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. What do you mean by "When the dataset includes no rows with a PurchQty greater than CurrStock, no rows are returned"? In your sample data 4th record (productcode BB400) which has PurchQty>CurrStock is beign returned by my code.

Comment: try this dataset...

`insert into #tmp values (1001,'AB101','14-Dec-2016',9,14)`
`insert into #tmp values (1111,'AB101','01-Jan-2017',8,14)`
`insert into #tmp values (1223,'AB101','15-Jan-2017',2,14)`
`insert into #tmp values (1233,'BB400','02-Jan-2017',30,40)`
`insert into #tmp values (1321,'AB101','31-Jan-2017',8,14)`
`insert into #tmp values (1400,'BB400','12-Dec-2016',20,40)`
`insert into #tmp VALUES (1456,'CC200','13-Mar-2017',10,20)`
`insert into #tmp values (1457,'CC200','14-Mar-2017',10,20)`

Comment: Hmm...got it. Thanks!!